# Supporting 4 monitors with an AMD 7790 GPU

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, displayport

I am currently running a custom build with a Sapphire AMD 7790 GPU.  The GPU has 4 ports in the back - two DVI, one HDMI, and one DisplayPort.  I had my build running fine with three monitors (two DVI and one HDMI), but I recently got a fourth, and it seems like 3 is the limit.

When I connected my 4th monitor, I used a passive DisplayPort to HDMI adapater.  I did a little preliminary research, and it seems like AMD cards can only support a select number of "legacy" outputs (HDMI/DVI).  So I went out today, and bought a straight DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable since my monitor had the input.  However, it's still not working for me.

There isn't a descriptive error - it just says "The display settings could not be saved..." but still recognizes my fourth monitor.

[image]

I don't think the problem is with the amount of pixels - I changed all monitors to the lowest output resolution, and I still couldn't extend my desktop to the fourth.  How might I go about diagnosing and fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This videocard is limited to only show a max of 3 outputs at the same time.

This really is a limitation of the Graphics Card. If you want more monitors, you will need a second graphics card or replace the card altogether with one that supports it.

If your PC has an onboard graphics card, it may be possible to use it to get that 4th display running though. But make sure you can see the display using one DVI, one HDMI and one Display Port before connecting the fourth monitor to the onboard graphics card.

Comment: Drats, that's what I was thinking.  Thankfully my GPU is fairly cheap these days so I picked one up for $60.  Makes sense in the long run since I plan to max out at 6 monitors.  Thanks.